# Difference between GregorianCalendar class and Calendar class in java?

Tags: java, class, calendar

While using both classes I found that for creating an object for respective classes 
Like

```
GregorianCalendar today = new GregorianCalendar ();
```

> Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

Why it is so? And what is benefits of using one over another?

Comment: Calendar is an abstract class. You need an actual implementation to get an instance of it. GregorianCalendar is, well the implementation of the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar). Calendar.getInstance() will return a GregorianCalendar, BuddhistCalendar or JapaneseImperialCalendar depending on the locale.

Comment: GregorianCalendar support leap year which means every 4 year you get one extra day in February 29/2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In most locales, when you write `Calendar.getInstance()`, it will create a `GregorianCalendar` object.  But there are a few exceptions.  Your locale could be set to give you a `JapaneseImperialCalendar` or a `BuddhistCalendar`.

If you really need your `Calendar` to be a `GregorianCalendar`, then you can explicitly write `new GregorianCalendar()`.  But it's generally considered better form to let the JVM choose the right kind of `Calendar` based on the locale.  That is, you should write `Calendar.getInstance()`, and be prepared to deal with the possibility of using one of the other calendar types.

There is no logic in the `Calendar` class for `getInstance()` to return one of the other types of calendar, such as those used in Iran or Saudi Arabia.

Answer (score 1):

The Calendar Class is nothing but an Abstract Class.The primary reason for making it abstract is that there are multiple types of Calendars available all over the world.